# How to get offset of a current widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to draw a widget whenever a user presses the screen.
Currently I am doing this by storing a list of widgets and when ontapup is fired on the gesture i am adding to a list of widgets.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget draw = new Text("A");
List<Widget> children = new List<Widget>();
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: const Text('Heading'),
    leading: new Icon(Icons.question_answer),
  ),
  body: new GestureDetector(
    onTapUp: (details) {
      setState(() {
          children.add(new Positioned(
            left: details.globalPosition.dx,
            top: details.globalPosition.dy,
            child: draw,
          ));
         });
    },
    child: new Stack(children: children)
    ...
```

So my code is working I am drawing the widget when I click but my problem is that when adding the new Positioned() to stack the position is based on the screen which does not include the appbar offset. Is there a way to get the stacks initial x/y position? Or is there a way to get the appbars height? How do I get a widgets position or height/width?

Answer (score 5):

Ok for anyone else who has the same issue I needed to create my own widget and use

```
context.findRenderObject()
```

and

```
globalToLocal()
```

Just FYI global to local did not work while in the one solution I needed to make it its own widget.

Answer (score 0):

To get the offset of a widget, you must get the `renderObject`, cast it as a `RenderBox`, and then convert it's local position to a global position. Like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
  Offset widgetOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  print("X: ${widgetOffset.dx}");
  print("Y: ${widgetOffset.dy}");
}
```

If you need the position of a child widget, you can wrap that child in a `LayoutBuilder`, like this:

```
Container(
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints box) {
      RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
      Offset widgetOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      print("X: ${widgetOffset.dx}");
      print("Y: ${widgetOffset.dy}");
    }
  )
)
```