# WebView into SizedBox Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to add a custom webview into a sizedBox in flutter... I've tried to do that but there is an error:

code:

```
@override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
         floatingActionButton: new Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
                new GestureDetector(
                  child: new Image.network("http://modernworfare.altervista.org/pause.png", width: 80.0,),
                  onTap: (){stop(); _showSnackBar();}, 
                ),
                new GestureDetector(
                  child: new Image.network("http://modernworfare.altervista.org/bg.png",width: 80.0,),
                  onTap: (){play(); _showSnackBar2();},
                ),
              ],
         ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
        new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Image.network("https://scontent-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/16864236_1836092593321492_1828236030296093399_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=817190c0ef6ac6e3076582905997f3e9&oe=5B81BFF9"),
          new Divider(),
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text("  WEBSITE  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                border: new Border.all(
                  width: 4.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text("  SOCIAL  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                border: new Border.all(
                  width: 4.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text("  SHOP  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                border: new Border.all(
                  width: 4.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text("  CONTACT  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                border: new Border.all(
                  width: 4.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              )],
          ),
          new Text("hi",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white), ), 
          new SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
            width: 600.0,
            child: webview.launch("url",
            )
          ),  
          ],
        )],
      ),
    );
  }
```

error:

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

any suggestions or ideas?
is it possible to do that?
maybe adding a future builder or something like that?

Answer (score 6):

**Issue:** Webview is not giving you full height for calculating its height you need to find the total content height when page is finished.

Here is the solution I found from [here](https://gist.github.com/SPodjasek/2f43fe45076976c16d830c749f992a1a)

```
StreamBuilder<double>(
          initialData: 100,
          stream: streamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Container(
              height: snapshot.data,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl:
                    'data:text/html;base64,${base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(contentText))}',
                onPageFinished: (some) async {
                  double height = double.parse(
                      await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
                          "document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"));
                  streamController.add(height);

                },
                onWebViewCreated: (_controller) {
                  _webViewController = _controller;
                },
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              ),
            );
          }
        );
```

> Note: I have used here streambuilder to avoid unnecessary "setstate" while building widget.

Please let me know if this solutions works or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which allows you to add inline webviews through the `InAppWebView` widget and much more.

So, you can add the `InAppWebView` widget like this in your code:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      floatingActionButton: new Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            child: new Image.network("http://modernworfare.altervista.org/pause.png", width: 80.0,),
            onTap: (){stop(); _showSnackBar();},
          ),
          new GestureDetector(
            child: new Image.network("http://modernworfare.altervista.org/bg.png",width: 80.0,),
            onTap: (){play(); _showSnackBar2();},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.network("https://scontent-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/16864236_1836092593321492_1828236030296093399_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=817190c0ef6ac6e3076582905997f3e9&oe=5B81BFF9"),
              new Divider(),
              new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Text("  WEBSITE  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      border: new Border.all(
                        width: 4.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Text("  SOCIAL  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      border: new Border.all(
                        width: 4.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Text("  SHOP  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      border: new Border.all(
                        width: 4.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Text("  CONTACT  ", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,)),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      border: new Border.all(
                        width: 4.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )],
              ),
              new Text("hi",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white), ),
              new SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 600.0,
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                  )
              ),
            ],
          )],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives me an error:

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:24979/0qp0Vss15Zs=/

Answer (score 1):

Here's [webview_flutter_plus](https://github.com/shah-xad/webview_flutter_plus) an extension of webview_flutter which allows getting the height of Web content which will allow you to use it even in a listview, this also helps to load HTML, CSS and Javascript content even from Assets or Strings. This inherits all features of webview_flutter with minor API changes.

Answer (score 0):

Which webview plugin are you using? Assuming `flutter_webview_plugin`, note the caveat `The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view.`.

`launch()` doesn't return a `Widget`; it returns `Future<Null>`, so even if you wait for the Future to complete you don't get a Widget. This is the point of the caveat: the webview sits (visually) on top of your Flutter app - it isn't a Flutter Widget.

You can position and size this floating webview with

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url,
              fullScreen: false,
              rect: new Rect.fromLTWH(
                  0.0, 
                  0.0, 
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 
                  300.0));
```

if you can calculate its absolute position.

Using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782591/how-to-get-offset-of-a-current-widget) you can find the top, left corner of a Widget over which you could position your webview with:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RenderObject ro = context.findRenderObject();
    if (ro is RenderBox) {
      print(ro.localToGlobal(new Offset(0.0, 0.0)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An inline WebView (a WebView widget in the widget tree) isn't supported yet. As far as I see on Flutter repo, there's no easy solution for it soon. If you just want to display rich text or html document, there's an offical widget named [RichText](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) or some [packages](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=html) releated to html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_webview_plugin 0.3.10](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-readme-tab-)

it has a widget that is very simple to use, following is the code for your reference:

```
new WebviewScaffold(
      url: selectedUrl,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget webview'),
      ),
      withZoom: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
      initialChild: Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('Waiting.....'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```