# The getter 'stream' was called on null

Tags: flutter, webview, stream-builder

I try to make a webview and I want to get the height of the webView and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880488/9095820)

But I get the following error:

[image]

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AnnouncementWebView(dirty, state: _AnnouncementWebViewState#d4695):
The getter 'stream' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: stream
```

This is my code:

```
  num _stackToView = 1;
  double contentHeight = 0;
  WebViewController _webViewController;
  StreamController<double> streamController;


      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _stackToView,
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<double>(
            initialData: 100,
            stream: streamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Container(
                height: snapshot.data,
                child: WebView(
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  initialUrl: widget.slug,
                  onPageFinished: (String url) async {
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                      double height = double.parse(
                          await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
                              "document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"));
                      streamController.add(height);
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      _stackToView = 0;
                    });
                  },
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController c) {
                    _webViewController = c;
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
        ],
      ),
```

I don't know why I get the error above. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You haven’t initialized the stream controller so when you try to use it it is null.

To fix this initialize the stream controller in initState (and don’t forget to close it in dispose) or alternatively forget about the stream and just use setState with a double field for the content Height