# Bottom Overflowed By Infinity Pixels in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used the Webview script data loading from the website. only data display from post title but Webview data are not showing instead Bottom Overflowed By Infinity Pixels are display in the screen. I cant find out my problem.Please give me suggestion.

```
  body: Container(
        height: 100,
        child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children:[
            Text(widget.title,
            textAlign:TextAlign.start,
             style: TextStyle(fontSize:19,  )
            ),
            WebView(
              navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                print('allowing navigation to $request');
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              initialUrl:'data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64',
              onWebResourceError: (error) {
                //EasyLoading.dismiss();
              },
              onPageFinished: (finish) {
                //EasyLoading.dismiss();
              },
            ),
          ],
    
        )
        )
      ),
```

Comment: remove container and column,you cannot use webview like this,for that use `flutter_inappwebview` https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview package

Comment: already remove the container but i already used SingleChildScrollView. Bottom Overflowed By Infinity Pixels problem is fix. But webview data dont showing? Post title & webview both would be display.

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil i used & fix it but webview data are not display.

Comment: @Abhijith. do you have such as script ?

Comment: @phplover Can you add your updated code

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355360/webview-into-sizedbox-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap webview with expanded().

Full Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView Demo'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("widget.title",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                  )),
              Expanded(
                  child: WebView(
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                  print('allowing navigation to $request');
                  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                },
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
                onWebResourceError: (error) {
                  //EasyLoading.dismiss();
                },
                onPageFinished: (finish) {
                  //EasyLoading.dismiss();
                },
              )),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```